# how to send request from Asp.net MVC to external api in multipart/form-data type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to send the uploaded file from my controller to another API outside my project.
the target API accept requests in type multipart/form-data

I read the uploaded file from current context

my problem is how to send request multipart/form-data and attach the uploaded file on it

I tried to do it client side but I couldn't because the cross-domain issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an Http request to that API.

Here is an example of how to make an Http request using `HttpClient`, and sending a file as an attachment.

The `filePath` parameter can be the uploaded file from the MVC.

```
public async Task SendAsync(string filePath)
{
    string url = "http://localhost/api/method";

    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    var fileContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filePath));
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "file.txt";
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name = "file";
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
    content.Add(fileContent);

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

```js
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace WebService.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // Controller methods not shown...
    }
}
```